# remove all text in brackets javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Any suggestion on how to remove text content in brackets?

Example:

```
<span id="new">Welcome [something.....] home</span>
<span id="new">The Jeep is (asdjfl... ect) nice</span>

var myString = document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0];
myString.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/, '');
```

Goal:

- Welcome home
- The Jeep is nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to match `(....)` or `[.......]`

```js
let element = document.querySelector('span')
element.innerText = element.innerText.replace(/(\(.*\)|\[.*\]) /,'').trim()
```

```html
<span>Welcome [something.....] home</span>
```

Comment: thx @dominik , any suggestion how to display it in the span tag (not only in the console.log) ?